# custom tableviewcell.xib not populating tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've run into an annoying issue that I cannot for the life of me find out. I know this has been covered and as far as I know i've done everything right but I can't get this custom cell to show up on the simulator.

I'm having this issue with a table view and a collection view as well, I figure results can be seen the same way for both so if you can just help me with the table view it'd be greatly appreciated. Here goes:

The following code is from the View Controller's .m file and as you can see in the viewdidload method, I've registered the nib and gave the reuse identifier 'tableViewCell'. Now correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe I'm supposed to give this identifier to the prototype cell in storyboard and leave the reuse identifier for the xib blank. In other words, the only places I'm supposed to be using the 'tableViewCell' identifier is for the prototype cell, in the viewdidload method, and the cellforRowAtIndexPath method, right? Please let me know if I'm missing any steps, thank you in advance:

```
#import "headEndChassisViewController.h"
#import "HeadEndChassisTableViewCell.h"

@interface headEndChassisViewController ()

@end

@implementation headEndChassisViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"headEndChassisCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.headEndChassisCollectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"headEndCell"];

    UINib *tableViewCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"HeadEndChassisTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.headEndChassisTableView registerNib:tableViewCellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"tableViewCell"];


    //The code below configures the textviews underneath the CollectionView

    [[self.slotNumberTextView layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [[self.slotNumberTextView layer] setBorderWidth:1];
    [[self.slotNumberTextView layer] setCornerRadius:1];
     self.slotNumberTextView.editable = NO;

    [[self.slotStatusTextView layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [[self.slotStatusTextView layer] setBorderWidth:1];
    [[self.slotStatusTextView layer] setCornerRadius:1];
    self.slotStatusTextView.editable = NO;

    [[self.bandTextView layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [[self.bandTextView layer] setBorderWidth:1];
    [[self.bandTextView layer] setCornerRadius:1];
    self.bandTextView.editable = NO;

    [[self.typeTextView layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [[self.typeTextView layer] setBorderWidth:1];
    [[self.typeTextView layer] setCornerRadius:1];
    self.typeTextView.editable = NO;

    //Code below configures the input power textview corner radius

    [[self.inputPowerTextView layer] setCornerRadius:3.3];

    //Code below configures border for Apply and Reset Buttons

    [[_resetButtonProperty layer]setBorderWidth:1.0f];
    [[_applyButtonProperty layer]setBorderWidth:1.0f];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

#pragma mark - Collection View

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 12;
}
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"headEndCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return cell;
}




#pragma mark - Table View

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 8;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)resetButton:(id)sender {
}

- (IBAction)applyButton:(id)sender {
}
@end
```

Comment: Does `cellNib` end up being nil?  If it does it means it couldn't find your nib.  Is the cell in the xib a subclass of `UITableViewCell`?  If it's not then it won't be able to dequeue it.  Is the reuse identifier the same in the xib `tableViewCell`?  if not it won't be able to dequeue it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a number of things.

1st did you set the delegate and datasource of the table view and collection view? This gets commonly missed (done it myself a few times). I don't see it in viewDidLoad so you would have to have done it in your storyboard. You didn't mention that you tried logging out cell for row either which leads me to believe this is the root of the problem and given you are not getting errors or crashing this is my best bet.

2nd it could be how you are loading your nib. I believe you don't need to do this in code in your case. I think you can just drag a UITableView cell into your table view, set the reuse, and set the class in inspector. If I am mistaken loading nibs as described in [this](https://horseshoe7.wordpress.com/2013/04/05/quick-reference-load-a-uiview-created-in-a-nib/) blog also worked for me in the past.

Hoping that helps.

Comment: wow I feel like an idiot, turned out to be setting the datasource and delegate. thank you sir.

Comment: Like I said it gets commonly missed and I have done it myself too many time. Glad I was able to help.